# Google Organization Chart from SharePoint list items

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, rest, custom-list

I created a Google Organization Chart on SharePoint using the answer from the following question on Stack Overflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796219/organization-chart-from-sharepoint-list-items

Items for the Organization Chart are retrieved from a Custom SharePoint List using REST and Javascript.

My question is, how should I modify the code below to show job titles below each name in the Organization Chart?
(Job titles are stored in the custom SharePoint list)

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["orgchart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(displayChart);


 function displayChart()
 {
     loadListItems('Organization_Chart')
     .done(function(data){
          var items = data.d.results;     
          drawChart(items); 
     })
     .fail(function(error){
          console.log(error);
     });
 }

function drawChart(items) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
    data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
         data.addRow([items[i]['Title'],items[i]['Manager']['Title'],'']);
     }    
     var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
     chart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true });
}


function loadListItems(listTitle){
     return $.ajax({            
             url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items?$select=*,Title,Manager/Title&$expand=Manager",
             type: "GET",
             headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
             },
             error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
     });             
}
</script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Custom SharePoint List stores each employee's name, manager, and job title.

[image: Organization Chart SharePoint List]

SharePoint List has the following schema:

```
Field Name  Type 
Title       Text 
Manager     Lookup
Job_Title   Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to concatenate `items[i]['Title']` with `items[i]['Job_Title']` at below line.

```
data.addRow([items[i]['Title'] +'</br>' + items[i]['Job_Title'],items[i]['Manager']['Title'],'']);
```

**The Output based on my test**

[image]

Unfortunately, the above change would work only for one level org chart, because the Goole Org-Chart code mainly depends on the `Name` column that now holds a value `'Employee name + Job Title'` and this value will not match any manager name in your Manager List!

So, I would suggest showing the `Jobitle` as a **tooltip** instead of a new line to get Org chart work for multiple levels as below

```
data.addRow([items[i]['Title'],items[i]['Manager']['Title'],items[i]['Job_Title']]);
```

[image]

**The full code**

```
<script src="http://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["orgchart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(displayChart);


 function displayChart()
 {
     loadListItems('Qassas Chart')
     .done(function(data){
          var items = data.d.results;     
          drawChart(items); 
     })
     .fail(function(error){
          console.log(error);
     });
 }

function drawChart(items) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
    data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
         data.addRow([items[i]['Title'],items[i]['Manager']['Title'],items[i]['Job_Title']]);
     }    
     var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
     chart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true });
}


function loadListItems(listTitle){
     return $.ajax({            
             url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items?$select=*,Title,Manager/Title&$expand=Manager",
             type: "GET",
             headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
             },
             error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
     });             
}
</script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**Update**

Based on the reported issue in the comments, Please make sure that you have provided the correct field name for `"Job_Title"`

In my case, I got the same result when I have provided an incorrect field name at `items[i]['Job_Title']` as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mohamed. While it makes sense to resolve my issue, unfortunately, I am not getting the intended result. The job titles are showing up as "undefined" and the hierarchy is broken. Please see the image link for the org chart before and after. [link](https://i.imgur.com/GBk6AmU.png)

Comment: @Devon this would happen if you have provided an incorrect *Job_Title* field name, please, check the updated answer and feedback us!

Comment: Thank you for the update Mohamed. I double-checked the field name in "Column Settings" and noticed while the Column name was Job_Title the field was actually JobTitle. Now my job titles are showing up correctly. However, I am still left with the broken hierarchy as shown in the link in my first comment.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118502/discussion-on-answer-by-mohamed-el-qassas-mvp-google-organization-chart-from-sha).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to show job titles below each name in a multi-level Google Org Chart while keeping the hierarchy intact.

Using the documentation on https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart, I was able to modify the following line provided by Mohamed El-Qassas MVP...

```
data.addRow([items[i]['Title'] +'</br>' + items[i]['Job_Title'],items[i]['Manager']['Title'],'']);
```

...and replace it with

```
data.addRow([{'v':items[i]['Title'], 'f':items[i]['Title'] + items[i]['JobTitle']},items[i]['Manager']['Title'],'']);
```